# Expanding directory in Node.js glob

Tags: node.js, glob

If I'm passing to the glob some masks like this `some/path/*.txt` -everything is ok. But when I'm passing this mask `some/path` - it will not expand this directory. Is it some option for expanding directories?

Comment: Expand how? You're feeding it a full path, nothing to expand. Also, which globbing package are you using?

Comment: I mean - recursive go to the directory and find all files.

I am using this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Comment: You can use `some/path/**`

Comment: Just wondering: did my answer help you? Just to remove it if not

Answer (score 0):

Just use `*` without any extension so that it will expand to all the elements in the directory:

```
some/path/*
```